# How to publish(deploy) multiple zip files to artifactory using gradle?

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I would like to upload multiple zip files(from different directories) to artifactory using gradle script. I was able to upload single distribution using below code.

```
    distributions {
        main {
            baseName = 'sample'
            contents {
                  from{'src/main/dist/sample'} 
            }
        }

    }
    publishing {
        repositories {
            maven {
                url "${artifactoryURL}/myFiles"
                credentials {
                    username artifactoryUser
                    password artifactoryPassword
                }
            }
        }
        publications {
            distribution(MavenPublication) {
                groupId 'com.test'
                artifactId 'sample'
                version version
                artifact (distZip) {
                }
            }
    }
    }
```

Please help in uploading multiple zip files from different source ("src/main/dist/second").

Answer (score 1):

This is full example of build.gragle. To publish zips you should run `distZip artifactoryPublish`

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jfrog.buildinfo:build-info-extractor-gradle:3.1.1"
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.jfrog.artifactory'
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'
apply plugin: 'distribution'

//Defining list of our distributions, every value is map which contains value and version of every distribution
def dists = [
    [name:'sample', version: 1], 
    [name:'second', version: 1]
]

distributions {
    //Creating distribution from each value of the distributions list defined above
    dists.each { dist ->
        "$dist.name" {
            baseName = "$dist.name"
            contents {
                from{"src/main/dist/${dist.name}"} 
            }
        }
    }
}

//Every new distribution creates task "${distributionName}DistZip" so we make posible to run them with base task distZip
distZip.dependsOn {
    tasks.findAll{ task -> task.name.endsWith('DistZip') }
}

publishing {
    publications {
        //Again iterating list to make publication for every distribution
        dists.each { dist ->
            //Every publication has name of the distibution
            "$dist.name"(MavenPublication) {
                groupId "test"
                version = dist.version
                artifactId = dist.name

                artifact("$buildDir/distributions/${dist.name}.zip")
            }
        }
    }
}

artifactory {
    contextUrl = "$URL"
    publish {
        repository {
            repoKey = 'REPO_KEY'

            username = USER_NAME
            password = PASSWORD
        }
        defaults {
            //Publish every distribution to Artifactory
            dists.each { dist ->
                publications(dist.name)
            }
        }
    }
}
```